# MS Excel 2016 conditional formatting

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to do conditional formatting on one cell based on different conditions of five other cells.

If the value in cell D1 is lower or equal to either cell N1, O1, or P1 etc. then cell D1 needs to match the color of either cell N1, O1, or P1 etc. So far, cell D1 only changed color to first reference and not the rest.

If I change Precedence of Rules then the color of D1 becomes whatever rule is first and not the one that it applies to. What should I do?

Comment: What condition did you try on D1 and the related cells?

Comment: Current selection: Cell Value <=$O1 [format] red [applies to] =$D$1.  Did the same for other cells P, Q, etc. with different format colors.

Comment: What is the condition in O1 to color?

Comment: [mm]:ss.00 - it is times for swimmers to achieve - so if their time in D1 is equal or lower than any one of the other 5 then D1 needs to take that color of time that is in O1 or P1 etc.

Comment: O1, P1, Q1 etc. have already been formatted in color text

Comment: How do you set the color in O1, P1? and what if D1 <= to 2 cells at the same time O1 and P1 which color you want?

Comment: Think that is the issue - O1, P1 etc. have been formatted with colored text.  I refer the color of text in rule to D1.  But at some point D1 can be <= than O1 and P1 - but only O1 color then show -P1 rule is ignored

Comment: Sure if 2 cells match the condition you cannot choose 2 colors

Comment: O1, P1, Q1, R1, S1 are progressively lower times

Comment: You need a formula for D1 <= the nearest value

Comment: Hmmmm - so that means I need to brush up on formulas - a little bit rusty in that department ^_^ Anyway that I can upload screenshots to show what I did?

Comment: =and(D1<=O1,Index(O1:Q1,Match(D1,O1:Q1,1))=O1) something like that for each color you change O1 with P1, Q1 and keep O1:Q1 the same